# How to add hours and minutes to a time in string form?

Tags: php, datetime

How can we add time interval to a time in string form.

```
$time = '10 : 00 : AM'; //initial time
$interval = '01 : 30'; //interval to be added

$newtime = $time + $interval;//how to do this

echo $newtime; //required: 11 : 30 : AM
```

Comment: And have you tried anything. If so please show us your attempts, so this does not look like a _Do it for me_ question

Comment: Read about [DateTime::add()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php)

Comment: `$time = strtotime('10 : 00 : AM');
$interval = strtotime('01 : 30'); 
$newtime = $time + $interval;echo date('h : i : a',$newtime);`

Comment: You can use explode() here to differentiate parts of your time then after converting indiviual time unit to interger and then   add required time. Then agin recreate that string by converting int to string and concatinating the colon.

Comment: @TarangP it is returning `07 : 00 : pm` instead of `11 : 30 : am`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The odd layouts of the text times make this a little fiddly but this will work

```
<?php
$in = '10 : 00 : AM';
$interval = '01 : 30';

$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('H : i : A', $in);

$interval = str_replace([' ',':'],['','H'], $interval);
$interval = 'PT'. $interval . 'M';

$dt->add(new DateInterval($interval));

echo $dt->format('H:i:s') . PHP_EOL;
```